# Pandas built in function to handle concatenated data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following data set.

```
id_number   type                               amount    date
1           employer contributioncontribution  $100$200  1/1/2023
2           employer contributioncontribution  $100$200  2/1/2023
```

The data should look like this

```
id_number   type                   amount date
1           employer contribution   $100  1/1/2023
1           contribution            $200  1/1/2023
2           employer contribution   $100  2/1/2023
2           contribution            $200  2/1/2023
```

Are there any built in pandas features to deconvolute this data? I feel like the best approach is to just parse each row and create a new data frame from the text.